# Detect if running from the command line in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a use case where we need to modify application flow if the application is being run from the command line via Artisan (migrations, seeds, route:list).

In Laravel 4 this could be done like this:

```
App::runningInConsole()
```

Is there an equivalent in Laravel 5?

Using the Environment (.env) variables isn't preferred in this case as these commands occasionally need to be run on production (pointing to production resources) and I'd prefer to avoid resorting to duplicate (.env.commandline) files.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use the PHP function `php_sapi_name` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php), to found out if the script was launched from a command or not.

In your case, you should check something like

```
if (strpos(php_sapi_name(), 'cli') !== false) {
    // Run from command
}
```

You may have to check the doc to find the proper value to check in each case though. (It may differ sometimes, but basically there should always be a different output from a script launched through a command)

Comment: This works, was hoping for a built in solution as before but further research yields that functionality has been deprecated. Marking as the solution.

Comment: @ForrestMarvez I'm not 100% sure, but I think it has been marked as deprecated on Laravel 5 because the result of the function wasn't always the same on each server / config.

Answer (score 47):

Not sure about any prior versions but in **Laravel 5.2** you can still do `App::runningInConsole()` although it's not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I'm able to use it in version `5.0.35`.

Comment: verified working in `5.4.36` probably just a namespace issue.use `\App::runningInConsole()`

Comment: app()->runningInConsole()

Comment: Also available in Laravel 5.7

Comment: laravel 5.8 works with `App::runningInConsole()` and `app()->runningInConsole()`

Comment: Working in 6.0 as well!

Answer (score 21):

As of Laravel 5.1 this works... `$app->runningInConsole()`
https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.html

Basic usage:

```
if (! $app->runningInConsole()) {
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Anyone can use laravel `app()` helper function to avoid any namespace related issue. So to check if script is running in cli or browser, can be using this line of code `app()->runningInConsole()`

**Basic usage:**

```
if ( app()->runningInConsole() ){
    // it's console.
}
```